# Why am I getting "Constructor must be initialized at declaration" google closure compiler warning?

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-closure-compiler

Consider this piece of code:

```
AEP: {
    Module: {
        _instances: {},
        get: function(module) {
            return (AEP.Module._instances[module.id] || (AEP.Module._instances[module.id] = new AEP.Module.Instance(module)));
        },
        implement: function(module, implementation) {
            AEP.Module.get({id: module}).dispatch(implementation(AEP));
        },
        /**
         * @param module
         * @constructor
         */
        Instance: function(module) {
            AEP.Event.apply(this, arguments);
            AEP.Utility.loadJSFile(module.url);
        }
    }
//...
}
```

I am getting this GCC warning:

```
WARNING - Constructor AEP.Module.Instance must be initialized at declaration
```

Why is that?

Comment: I don't know why they want a declaration, but If you make a function declaration instead (along with the annotation), then assign the function to the object, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that check doesn't recognize the label as an assignment. Try this:

```
AEP: {
    Module: {
        _instances: {},
        get: function(module) {
            return (AEP.Module._instances[module.id] || (AEP.Module._instances[module.id] = new AEP.Module.Instance(module)));
        },
        implement: function(module, implementation) {
            AEP.Module.get({id: module}).dispatch(implementation(AEP));
        },
        Instance:
          /**
           * @param module
           * @constructor
           */
          function(module) {
            AEP.Event.apply(this, arguments);
            AEP.Utility.loadJSFile(module.url);
          }
    }
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Crazy Train explained already; here is an example:

```
var AEP= {
    Module: {
        _instances: {},
        get: function(module) {
            window['console'].log("get");
        },
        implement: function(module, implementation) {
            window['console'].log("implement");
        }
    }
};
/**
* @param module
* @constructor*/
AEP.Module.Instance= function(module) {
  window['console'].log("instance");
};
```